# How to set condition for input to close event in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Reference from https://codepen.io/Elavarasan11/pen/opgLaK

When i clicked on Search, Li tag will display,

And now i need to close the Li tag, when i clicked outside of search. So in order to close the li taken a methods and directives to close the event. and i need to add this.showsearchHistory = false; in order to close li.

```js
 data: {
    isActive: false
  },
 mounted(){
    $('.example').select2({
      placeholder: 'Please select',
    });
    
      $('.example').on('select2:unselect',function(e){
        //console.log(e)
      });
    
  },  
  methods: {
    show: function(){
        this.isActive = true;
    },
    hide: function() {
        this.isActive = false;
    },    
  }
      directives: {
      'click-outside': {
        bind: function(el, binding, vNode) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
            console.log(el)
            this.event = function (event) {
             if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target) || event.target.className === 
             "select2-selection__choice__remove" || event.target.className === "select2-search__field" )) {
                vnode.context[binding.expression](event);
              }
            };
            document.body.addEventListener('click', this.event)
          },
          unbind: function (el) {
            document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.event)
          },
        
      }
    }
```

```html
 <input
          class="form-control bg-light-blue"
          id="SearchText"
          type="text"
          v-model="search"
          @keydown.enter="enter"
          @click="onClick"
          @keyup.enter="processSearch"
          @input="change"
          @keyup="inputChanged"
          @keydown.down="onArrow"
          @keydown.up="onArrow"
          @keydown.space="preventLeadingSpace"
          
        />

         <ul class="list-inline" v-if="showSearchHistory" v-click-outside="hide" v-bind:class="{active: isActive}">
         
          <li
            class="list-inline-item list-group-item-primary"
            v-for="(item, index) in searchHistory
              .slice(-5)
              .reverse()
              .map((s) => s.trim())"
            :key="index"
            @click="selectPreviousSearch(index)"
          >
            {{ item }}
          </li>


        </ul>
```

Comment: What is your question? You provided a fully working snippet of code, and I am unsure what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry for that. With reference to codepen link, as shown there when clicked outside of li it is closing. The same code i tried to implement in my code above, But issue is li tag is not closing... I am thinking that because of in my code i did not place it correctly in input Or in the ul tag.

Comment: @SuitBoyApps, Can you please help me on this.

Comment: hello, I would love to. However I really do not understand the question, even after you have tried explaining it, I also do not understand why you are mixing jQuery and Vue at the same time

Comment: I have fixed that issue by taking the @focusout in input written one method for closing that.